# replace space in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to replace all the letters in a sentence to * (asterisks).

My code is

```
var password='hello world';
password.replace(/\S/g, '*');
```

All the letters are getting replaced but not the space.
How can that too be replaced ?

Comment: What don't you use <input type="password" ... /> ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\s` will match spaces

`\S` (capital S) will match everything BUT spaces

`.` will match every character

So to replace every character:

```
password.replace(/./g, '*');
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
password.replace(/[a-zA-Z|\s]/g, '*');
```

This matches letters and spaces but use the other answer if you ment all characters. Although even better use an input of type "password" if that will achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
var password='hello world';
password=password.replace(/[\S ]/g, '*');
```

Tested and illustrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/HSP2P/